# Is it possible to remove the vertical line in Gitlab editor mode?

Tags: gitlab

I am working on Gitlab, in edit mode, and a vertical line appears in the editor.

[image]

Is is possible to remove that vertical line, or am I stuck with it?

Comment: It's just a margin of the editor

Comment: @EdoardoVignati - I take it we can't remove it then?

Comment: I've never seen an option to remove it. Anyway it's only visible  in the editor, not in the saved file.

Comment: @EdoardoVignati - Ah! Thanks.